# Integrate javascript tts in angular 2 project

Tags: javascript, angular

I found myself in quite a pickle and I can't seem to solve it. What I'm trying to do is to import Articulate.js in my Angular2 project,but I can't seem to make it work. I've imported the scripts in index.html and angular-cli, but everytime I click the speak button it tells me:

```
speak is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

[This is the source code for the Articulate.js](https://github.com/acoti/articulate.js)

**speak.js**

```
function speak(obj) {
    $(obj).articulate('speak');
    };

    function pause() {
      $().articulate('pause');
    };

    function resume() {
      $().articulate('resume');
    };

    function stop() {
      $().articulate('stop');
    };
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import '../../../assets/speak.js';
import '../../../assets/articulate.min.js';
import '../../../assets/jquery.min.js';

declare var articulate: any;
declare var speak: any;
```

**app.html**

```
<div class="articulate-area">
    <button onclick="speak('div.card')">Speak Intro</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You should import all the jQuery plugins after jQuery import. Also the scripts should be included only once. Also it does not seem that you are using angular to handle events for this case - is there any reason for why you are calling event handler using onclick="..." (instead of (click)="doSomething()") and handling it in speak.js instead of app.component.ts file?

Comment: @RUKAclMortality And if I add the (click)="doSom()", how do I handle it from the speak.js?

Comment: you would handle it from your app.component.ts like: `export class AppComponent { doSom() { ... } }`. https://angular.io/guide/user-input